# How do you stop a streaming download with Play WS 2.5 in Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka-stream

I want to download the first few kb of an image, then get an InputStream from the content. Ultimately, I'm using `ImageIO` to get the dimensions of the image, and it only needs to read a little bit.

I have code working that quickly reads the image from a stream and returns after reading just a little of the image, but the download continues on in the background - costing transfer bandwidth.

I'm new to Akka Streams and couldn't quite figure out how to get from the docs for streaming in Play to being able to consume a little bit, grab it as in InputStream, and stop the download.

```
ws.url(uri).withMethod("GET").stream().map { res =>
  val is = res.body.runWith(StreamConverters.asInputStream())

  // Efficiently gets dimensions without needing the entire file
  val dimensions = dimensionsFromImageIo(is)

  // This doesn't stop the download :(
  is.close()
}
```

Then, I tried something like this, but neither calling `shutdown` or `abort` on the `killSwitch` stopped the download, which continues on in the background as I can see by monitoring my bandwidth.

```
ws.url(uri).withMethod("GET").stream().map { res =>
  val (killSwitch, is) = res.body
    .viaMat(KillSwitches.single)(Keep.right)
    .toMat(StreamConverters.asInputStream())(Keep.both)
    .run()

  val dimensions = dimensionsFromImageIo(is)
  is.close()

  // This doesn't stop the download either
  killSwitch.shutdown()
}
```